# How to make our iPad application to share files through iTunes

Tags: iphone, file-sharing

I have made an iPad application. Now i have a requirement to upload any file into my application shared/document folder from my System through iTunes.

I have learned from this link http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4094 that we can make our application for File Sharing. If our application has enabled File Sharing then our application will be seen under File Sharing Tab in iTunes.

So i want my app to be seen under File Sharing Tabs so that i can share any file into my application.

Please can anybody guide me through this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define this key in your info.plist file -

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
    <true/>
```

Comment: how can i put a restriction That only allows me to view file with .xyz extension. Can i do it ?

Comment: i am not 100 percent sure about this but you can do a trick. Use (.) before the file names that you don't want to show in itunes. Its working for me .

Comment: ooh ok .. so there is no legal way to let the application view only specific extension of files.  :( hmmm

Comment: By enabling this key, the user can see all files placed the "Documents" directory of your application. The files that you don't want the user to see, shouldn't be placed there, instead use other folders(eg. Library).