# iOS Application how to update file through iTunes

Tags: ios

Is it possible to update the file through iTunes and read it from the application? If yes, which way do I go about that.
To be clear, I want to have, say, a configuration file that is going to be distributed with my application, which I read at the start. Now if another such file is later downloaded through iTunes (from the user's computer, for instance), is it possible to read it? Where would it end up anyway? And which specific chapter of programming do I need to search about this.

I just need a general guidelines.

Thank you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613234/how-to-make-our-ipad-application-to-share-files-through-itunes

Comment: Thanks, after posting the question I figured that myself as well. However, I still cannot find an example that shows me how to access the files uploaded that way. Thanks.

Comment: The files end up in your Documents directory. The trick is detecting changes to the content of the Documents directory. Users can add, rename, and remove files. The changes can happen while your app is running as well as when it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have enable itunes file sharing in Plist as rmandy suggested, you can access those files in:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```